# Selenium c# Unable To Get Test To Fail When Looking For Text

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am validating the presents of text within an address field and the text is present but no matter what I put in the expected string the test passes

`string AddressLine1 = YourDetails.AddressLine1.GetCssValue("The Big Test House");`

Another input element I am trying to retrieve text from:

```
<input id="first_name_text_box" name="firstName" class="StyledInput-sc-1p20bfl iaFJkJ" value="Cal">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get an element's text, you should use `.Text` instead.

So you would use:

```
string AddressLine1 = YourDetails.AddressLine1.Text;
```

Assuming `YourDetails.AddressLine1` is a `WebElement`.

Comment: This works and doesnt work, this works on elements but not text boxes whereby I have input data; that returns an empty string ""

Comment: Depending on the HTML for the text boxes, you may need to do `.GetAttribute("value");`. It depends on where the element text is stored. If you inspect element, and you cannot see your input data in the HTML at all, then the DOM is not storing it at all -- meaning you cannot access it with Selenium either. If you edit your question with the HTML for the text box you are trying to retrieve, we can try to help more.

Comment: Right, so you would do `var input = MyInput.GetAttribute("value");` which will return `Cal`. This works with the assumption that `MyInput` is a `IWebElement` object, just like `YourDetails.AddressLine1` is from your sample.

Comment: So to get this right, does it look like the below:

`var FirstName1 = YD.FirstName.GetAttribute("Value");`  
or 
`var FirstName1 = YD.FirstName.GetAttribute("Cal");`

Because when I hover over the **FirstName1** in visual studios it comes back **NULL**

Comment: The first one, but lowercase `value`. You want to do `GetAttribute("value")` because value is the name of the HTML attribute you need. If `YD.FirstName` is null then the element has not been found — you may need a different selector strategy to locate this element. I would use `By.XPath("//input[@id='first_name_text_box']"))`

Comment: Still NULL unfortunately regardless of how I get the element; the required string is within the value="Cal". I will check with Dev and see what I am unable to see

Comment: Using the XPath should locate the element correctly, and calling `GerAttribute("value")` should retrieve "Cal"— my best guess is there may be an iframe element on the page which hides the element, or there is another element with the same XPath being located which may cause issues. If you post the full page HTML or a link to the page, I can try to assist further. The Dev may have better idea of what’s going on. I would try `var text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='first_name_text_box']")).GetAttribute("value");` to make sure PageObject is not issue here.

Comment: This method works on other fields so there must be some strange happenings for this particular set of fields. Thanks!

Comment: So we are over the hurdle, i can now get the text back using ```GetAttribute("value");``` but how do i validate that text against what I expect?

Comment: Depending on the purpose of your automation -- if you are testing, you can use a testing framework like NUnit and use the `Assert` class to `Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue);`. Your test will pass or fail based on the outcome of the `Assert` statement. This is a great NUnit guide to get you started: http://dotnetpattern.com/nunit-introduction

Comment: ```Assert.AreEqual(AddressLine1 .GetAttribute("value"), "My House"); ```

This works perfectly :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the conclusion

Assert.AreEqual(Addresses.AddressLine1 .GetAttribute("value"), "My House");

**Addresses.AddressLine1** is derived from the POM, which looks like this for those wondering -

**Namespace - Addresses**
`public IWebElement AddressLine1{ get { return driver.FindElement(By.id='first_line_of_address']")); } }`